# Remotion.Linq.dll not found

Tags: c#, windows-10-iot-core

A couple of days ago I (foolishly) decide to clean my NuGet cache, and now, whenever I build my project, I get the following error:

> Could not copy the file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\remotion.linq\2.1.1\lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80\Remotion.Linq.dll" because it was not found.

The problem here is that `Remotion.Linq.dl` is not even part of the project the is throwing the error. I have no idea what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered installing that Nuget package?

Comment: Doing it right now. I hadn't done it yet because I assumed `dotnet restore` restore all packages needed, and I definitely didn't install `Remotion.Linq` before. Not explicitly at least.

Comment: @Amy It didn't work. Same error.

Comment: Done! Installing it didn't change anything, but removing it did! After uninstalling the pack, everything went back on track.